# UnsatisfiableError in Anaconda Navigator while installing opencv in Anaconda Environments

Tags: windows-10, python, anaconda

I was trying to work with opencv. I tried installing the required files into my environment.
Two of the three files of opencv were easily installed but the one is giving me an error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> h5py==2.9.0=py37h5e291fa_0 -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0']
  - anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
  - h5py -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0']
  - hdf5
  - pkgs/main/win-64::importlib_metadata==0.8=py37_0 -> zipp[version='>=0.3.2']
  - pkgs/main/win-64::path.py==11.5.0=py37_0 -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
  - pkgs/main/win-64::zipp==0.3.3=py37_1
  - pytables -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0']
```

How can I resolve this error?